# R grep NAs from vector

Tags: r

How do I use `grep()` to get NAs from a vector?

i.e: when I try `grep(NA, c(1,NA))`

I get `[1] NA NA`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `is.na()`:

```
> vec <- c(1,NA)
> is.na(vec)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want the `NA`, try

```
> which(is.na(vec))
[1] 2
> vec[which(is.na(vec))]
[1] NA
> vec[is.na(vec)] # simpler, logical subscripting
[1] NA
```

If you don't, negate the output from `is.na()`:

```
> !is.na(vec)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
> which(!is.na(vec))
[1] 1
> vec[which(!is.na(vec))]
[1] 1
> vec[!is.na(vec)] ## simpler, logical subscripting
[1] 1
```

One reason your code doesn't work is that you gave `NA` as the pattern. To R this means that the pattern is not defined, so whether either of the elements of the vector match this pattern is also undefined - hence both are `NA` in the output.

Comment: `vec[which(!is.na(vec))]` is too complicated, it suffices to use `vec[!is.na(vec)]`.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is the wrong option here. Use the built-in function `is.na` instead.

```
> is.na(c(1,NA))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

EDIT: if you want the integer indices rather than true/falses (which is more like what `grep` returns), use `which(is.na())`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't; use `which` and `is.na` instead:

```
> which(is.na(c(1,NA)))
[1] 2
> which(is.na(c(NA,1,NA)))
[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `is.na(c(1, NA))`.